# How do I link a gzipped version of a stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, apache, gzip

This might be a duplicate question, but I couldn't find it.

1. My apache server has `mod_deflate` enabled
2. My server has the gzipped version of the css in my css folder

My question is, will my server automatically locate my gzipped file?

In other words, should my html look like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/my_css.css">`
And my server will automatically locate the gzipped css?

Or should it look like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/css/my_css.css.gz">`

Or do I do both?

Comment: With mod_deflate enabled, your apache server does zip the file on the fly. Just link your normal file and watch it in browser's developer tool.

Comment: so does that mean that I don't need to add the `.gz` file to my server? Sorry if that's a dumb question

Comment: Gzipping is typically done at the web server level.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_deflate.html to see how it works